# Issue with simple jquery slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So as a means of learning jquery I'm making my own slider where each image swipes to the left creating a nice effect, this is beacuse I change the left property of the absolutely positioned images container.

However I fail to make it move, what I do is capture the width of each image in the slider and mov the container accordingly.

My code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var interval = 2000; //will move to left 450px each X seconds
  var sliders = $('.slider_image'); //counts number of sliders
  var image_width = $('.slider_image').width();
  var index = 0;
  var show_index = 0;
  var scrolledPx = 0;

  setInterval(function() {

    if (scrolledPx >= image_width * sliders.length - 1) {

      $('.sliders_container').animate({
        'left': '0px'
      }, 2000);
      scrolledPx = 0;

    } else {

      $('.sliders_container').animate({
        'left': '-= ' + image_width + ''
      }, 1000);
      scrolledPx += image_width;
    }

  }, interval);
});
```

```css
/*SECTION SLIDER MARG START*/

.section_slider_marg_maincontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 275px;
  outline: 2px solid white;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.section_slider_marg_items_container {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: flex;
}

.section_slider_marg_item {
  height: 100%;
  width: 450px;
  outline: 2px solid red;
  background-size: cover;
}


/*SECTION SLIDER MARG END*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section class="section_slider_marg_maincontainer" style="">
  <div class="section_slider_marg_items_container sliders_container" style="">
    <div class="section_slider_marg_item slider_image" style="background-image:url('img/Res1.jpg');">1</div>
    <div class="section_slider_marg_item slider_image" style="background-image:url('img/Res1.jpg');">2</div>
    <div class="section_slider_marg_item slider_image" style="background-image:url('img/Res1.jpg');">3</div>
    <div class="section_slider_marg_item slider_image" style="background-image:url('img/Res1.jpg');">4</div>
    <div class="section_slider_marg_item slider_image" style="background-image:url('img/Res1.jpg');">5</div>
    <div class="section_slider_marg_item slider_image" style="background-image:url('img/Res1.jpg');">6</div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: Is it possible that because you are using the same image for each slide it appears as if its not moving? Not sure what image you are using though, i.e. if its just a plain color.

Comment: I edited the style to make it more apparent

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
.section_slider_marg_maincontainer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 275px;
  outline: 2px solid white;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.section_slider_marg_items_container {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  display: flex;
}

.section_slider_marg_item {
  height: 100%;
  width: 450px;
  outline: 2px solid red;
  background-size: cover;
}

.slider_image {display: none}

/* Slideshow container */
.sliders_container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  padding: 16px;
  margin-top: -22px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

</style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="section_slider_marg_items_container sliders_container">

 <div class="section_slider_marg_item slider_image">
  <img src="res1.jpg"></div>

<div class="section_slider_marg_item slider_image">
  <img src="res1.jpg"></div>



<a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
<a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>

</div>
<br>


<script>
var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("slider_image");

  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}    
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none";  
  }

  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  

}
</script>
```

Check out this and let me know if it does work